# split pdf by blank page?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to split pdf file into other pdf file. so in these case `I Use blank page` as separator (in main pdf file).

**`How to do this?`**

1. Detect White Page
2. Split Pdf File

Answer (score 1):

You can use PDFsharp for this.check out the following link for example

[Split pdf file](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=37&Itemid=48)